# How can two-time theories be compactified to 3+1 without any Kaluza-Klein remnants?

Tags: time, gauge-theory, spacetime-dimensions, compactification, kaluza-klein

I have recently been looking into the [two-time theories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_time_dimensions) and the implied concepts.

For me this seems slightly hard to grasp.

How can I see the basic concept in this theory in a fundamental way based on its implied interaction with normal 3+1 dimension?

I am interested specifically in how [gauge symmetries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_symmetry) that effectively reduce 2T-physics in 4+2 dimensions to 1T-physics in 3+1 dimensions without any [Kaluza-Klein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza-Klein_theory) remnants.

Comment: This article [here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2010/08/gauge-theory-in-12-dimensions.html) possibly says something about it, in particular the papers explained therein. But I have just detected and not yet read it.

Comment: [Here](http://motls.blogspot.com/2012/09/vafas-new-4d-string-theory.html) is another reference.

Comment: "slightly hard to grasp." My friend, if you have understood one time dimension, you are already a king among physicists.

Answer (score 2):

In [this](http://motls.blogspot.com/2010/08/gauge-theory-in-12-dimensions.html) blog post, a [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1008.4761) that derives by dimensional reduction well known super Yang-Mills (SYM) theories, such as N=1 SYM in 9+1 dimensions and N=4 SYM in 3+1 dimensions among other things using a SYM theory in 10+2 dimensions as a common more fundamental underlying theory.

As can be seen from looking at figure 1 of that paper

[image]

As stated below equation (3.1), if applying the method of deriving shadows of two time physics to obtain lower dimensional theories, Kaluza-Klein are avoided.